# Totally disconnected but not totally separated

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

A topological space $X$ is totally disconnected if all of its components are singletons, and $X$ is said to be totally separated if all of its quasi-components are singletons. The set of rational numbers as well as the Cantor set are both totally disconnected and totally separated. I need an example of a space which is totally disconnected but not totally separated i.e. a space whose components are singletons, but at least one of its quasi-components consist of more than one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard example of such a space is [Cantor's leaky tent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan). It has a single quasi-component, which is the whole space.