# Is there a suitable name for spaces where quasi-components are singletons?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, terminology

I am familiar with totally disconnected spaces. All components are singletons there.

Is there some terminology for spaces that satisfy the (stronger) condition of having only quasi-components that are singletons?

I thought of a name myself (totally separated) but maybe this is in use already for something else.

Also I am willing to subject to what is already there.

Thank you.

Comment: Apparently the term is "totally separated": https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Totally_Separated_Space

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you. Maybe once (long time ago) I knew and puzzling by search for a proper name it emerged while I was unaware.

Comment: In Engelking, General topology, a space is called *hereditarily disconnected*, if its components are singletons, hence what you call *totally disconnected*. In the historical notes to 6.2 he mentions that "at present the term *totally disconnected* is usually applied to a space X such that the quasi-component of any point $x \in X$ consists of the point x alone". Hence, according to Engelking, the term you are looking for is *totally disconnected*, indeed.

Comment: @Ulli Thank you for this information. I have made my choice (totally separated) but it is a good thing to have notion of these diversities in definitions. Actually it would be better if they did not exist but that will always remain to be not more than wishful thinking.

Comment: @drhab Sure! I also don't like the term *hereditarily disconnected*, since only the empty space is *really* hereditarily disconnected. I prefer your settings as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe "totally separated" actually is the standard term already - see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326245/totally-disconnected-but-not-totally-separated?rq=1) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Disconnected_spaces). Note that the latter source defines "totally separated" as "for all distinct points $p,q$, there is a partition of the space into open sets $U,V$ with $p\in U$ and $q\in V$," but that's clearly equivalent to all quasicomponents being singletons.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe once (long time ago) I knew and puzzling by search for a proper name it emerged while I was unaware. At the moment I am busy with Stone spaces (in my journey through logics).